# Do I need to add a fuse for a lamp circuit off a ring main?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, uk

In my flat I have a spur from the ring main to two double plug sockets either side of the bed. There is a 13amp fused spur switch between the ring main and the spur.  I want to extend the spur to go to 2 wall lamps (they have a on/off switch in the base).

Do I need another fused spur switch between the end socket and the wall lamps? If so why? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, Jason. New information belongs in your question, not down here. I've tagged UK, so no worries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only spur off a ring once but by installing a fused connection unit (FCU) as you have there, you can extend to the lamps under BS7671.
The FCU will have a maximum 13A fuse so this would be your design current for the spur.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need another fused spur switch between the end socket and the
> wall lamps? If so why?

Yes, you should use another fused spur (although it doesn't have to be switched) with a 3A fuse.

This will allow you to use thinner cable (1mm) to the wall lights.

Most modern lights would be rated for a 20A power circuit (as that's what's used in Europe) but it's still good practice to fuse down to 3A.

It also means that if you later rearrange the circuit and move the sockets on to the 32A ring, your lights are already fused down.